# Cocoa ITLibrary - ITLibMediaItem.location always nil/NULL

Tags: xcode, macos, frameworks, itunes

I am getting always *nil* ITLibMediaItem.location attribute.

```
    //            let library: ITLibrary = try ITLibrary(APIVersion: "1.0")
    //            library.reloadData()
    if let mediaItem = iTuneMediaItem {
        if let location = mediaItem.location{
            return location.path
        }else{
            print("nil location")
        }
    }else{
        print("nil mediaItem")
    }
```

If i enable commented line to reload library before get location it is working, but i don't want to reload library every time because it takes time if we have large iTunes playlist.

can please anyone explain how we can fix without reloading library every time?

**EDIT** :

I am using ITLibMediaItem from ITLibPlaylist.items[]

Answer (score 0):

I figure the fix is need to make static app level attribute of ITLibrary and reload once at init.